# Fluentd ElasticSearch Output - [401] Unauthorized

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I am testing fluentd using the following configuration.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/centos/service.log
  pos_file /home/centos/service.log.pos
  @label @SQLPAD
  tag sqlpad
  <parse>
  @type cri
    <parse>
    @type json
    </parse>
  </parse>
</source>
<label @SQLPAD>
  <match *.**>
    type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      user %{user}
      password %{pass}
      host <domain>.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com
      port 443
      scheme https
      logstash_format true
      ssl_verify false
  </store>
  </match>
</label>

<system>
  log_level debug
</system>
```

The connection is not being made and I got these logs:

```
2021-09-16 14:43:40 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. [401] Unauthorized
2021-09-16 14:43:40 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 14. Retry to communicate after 2 second(s).
2021-09-16 14:43:45 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. [401] Unauthorized
2021-09-16 14:43:45 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 13. Retry to communicate after 4 second(s).
2021-09-16 14:43:53 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. [401] Unauthorized
2021-09-16 14:43:53 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 12. Retry to communicate after 8 second(s).
```

Nevertheless, running `curl` on the same `fluentd` aggregator machine is working:

```
[centos@ip-172-168-45-176 ~]$  curl https://<user>:<pass>@<domain>.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_cat/indices
green open .kibana_-1773627903_databrewers_1 QIqQBSA4Rj6rYwL5nYNMpA 1 1 1 0 10.1kb    5kb
green open .kibana_1                         QTMRbaXGSASmdHF5Peo66g 1 1 3 6 33.9kb 16.9kb
green open .opendistro_security              qUusXLQLRFC26XuDZD3NjA 1 1 9 1 95.9kb 47.9kb
```

To test the user credentials I even created an index with some data, using curl.

Comment: the port number in <store> looks strange, are you sure to push your dataflow on the port 443 of elasticsearch (by default is 9200)

Comment: I think I saw a bug, already reported https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch/issues/919

Comment: this is the aws service which is a fork of Elasticsearch, so it runs differently